# How to copy dashboard to other organisations in Grafana

Tags: python, grafana, grafana-api

I'm using [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) to show some data. I have 20 organisations and they all use the same dashboards (Dash1, Dash2, Dash3). Thus I can use the same json data for all dashboards in all organisations.

But I do not want to update it manually every time when I change something, thus I'm trying to create a python script which will do it for me.

I run the script as follows:

```
python update_dashboards.py Dash1
```

The python code is as follows:

```
try:
    dashboard_name = sys.argv[1]
    response = settings.get_request_with_token(settings.api_url + "search?query=" + dashboard_name) 
    dashboard = json.loads(response)
    if len(dashboard) < 1:
        print("There is no dashboard data.")
    else:
        dashboard_data = dashboard[0]
        dashboard_uri = str(dashboard_data["uri"])
        dashboard_data = dashboard_api.get_dashboard(dashboard_uri)
        // Here I get dashboard details

except IndexError:
    print("Please provide dashboard name!")
```

Thus I give the name of the dashboard that I want to copy to all organisations.

With my code I get successfully the dashboard that I want to copy.

My question is how can I now use this dashboard to copy it to all other organizations?

Answer (score 0):

I'd think to use the [API](http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/dashboard/) to create new dashboards. You can use requests and create a payload with what you already have in your script. You also need a [key](http://docs.grafana.org/tutorials/api_org_token_howto/) to use the API.

```
payload = {"authorization": "yourkey", "content": thedashboard} 
url = yougrafanaaddress/api/dashboards/db
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```